# Affectiva C++ Linux SDK FrameDetector won't detect anything

Tags: affdex-sdk

Hi I'm trying out Affdex sdk for emotion detection from a webcam feed. Each frame is fed to a FrameDetector as shown in examples. But after few seconds, the nothing gets detected. Not even the face. The same set up works for PhotoDetector. I have correctly set up the timestamp (as was shown in one of the examples). I'm using this on Ubuntu 16.04 using C++

Any ideas as to why this behaviour?
Thanks.

FrameDetector initialized with 5 frame buffer.

Comment: Where are the examples you are referring to ?

Comment: https://github.com/Affectiva/cpp-sdk-samples/blob/master/opencv-webcam-demo/opencv-webcam-demo.cpp

Comment: hmm .. what's the compiler version ? The SDK was compiled using GCC 4.8.

Comment: did you figure this out?  It would be good to have an answer here.